# How can I use Matlab objects in compiled .NET assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have a basic Matlab class which I want to instantiate in C#.

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        Value
    end

    methods
        function obj=MyClass(v)
            obj.Value = v;
        end

        function display(obj)
            disp(obj.Value);
        end
    end    
end
```

This is then built into a .DLL file and imported in a C# project along with the associated Matlab namespaces (MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays, MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility).

On the C# side, I am trying to build an instantiation of this class thus:

```
        Untitled2.MLTestClass matlab = new Untitled2.MLTestClass();
        MWCharArray input = new MWCharArray("Initial");                       
        MWArray[] result = matlab.MyClass(1, input);
```

By the end of the last line of code, result.Length = 1 and result[0] = null. I was somehow expecting to obtain the reference to the newly created Matlab object somehow. I was wondering, is this even possible? And if yes, then how can this be accomplished? If no, is there a way around it? (I basically have a GUI component written in C# which I don't want to integrate in Matlab, but rather, the other way round).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [not possible](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4A45AC/index.html?product=MN&solution=1-4A45AC) to use Matlab classes inside .NET assemblies. 
There are numerous workarounds:

1. Define your variable as *global* , and access it with several functions that wrap its methods
2. Return your Matlab class as a value of field in struct.

Here is a code snippet for (1):

```
function CreateMyClass(st)
    global myClass;
    myClass = MyClass(st);
end

function DisplayMyClass()
    global myClass;
    myClass.display();
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :) The code snippet and the link itself have proved to be insightful.

Comment: @andrey-rubshtein what is currently the best way of doing it? I have multiples classes (with multiple methods) in matlab and each class has a demo script. I would like to generate one .NET assembly for each class.