# How to cleanly stop a .NET thread that is running a matlab dll function

Tags: c#, multithreading, matlab, dll, pass-by-reference

I compiled a Matlab DLL with namespace flagTest and class name test with this function:

```
function [ ] = flagTest( flag )
    while flag
        disp(flag);
        pause(1);
    end
end
```

I can call this dll function in c# like this:

```
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create test class object
            flagTest.test T = new flagTest.test();
            MWLogicalArray flag = new MWLogicalArray(true);
            //call matlab function flagTest
            T.flagTest(flag);
        }
    }
}
```

I am sorry if it causes any confusion since I call both my namespace and function `flagTest`.

What I want to do now is to put this `T.flagTest(flag)` function call on a thread  (which I know how to do), and change the value of `flag` to `false` as user click a button on the UI to stop the thread. In the real matlab function in our application, I will need to do quite some work such as finish reading the current file and write the data in memory to disk before I can stop the function thread. I cannot just stop the thread without doing anything in the matlab function.

I am wondering if there's anyway to achieve this functionality as I was not able to figure out how to pass an object by reference from .NET to Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you encapsulates the flag that controls your loop into your `test` class? For example:

```
classdef test < handle
    properties (Access = private)
        Running
    end

    methods
        function Start(this)
            if (this.Running)
                disp('Already Running');
                return;
            end

            this.Running = true;
            disp('Started');

            while (this.Running)
                pause(1);
                disp('Running');
            end

            disp('Stopped');
        end

        function Stop(this)
            this.Running = false;
        end
    end
enn
```

Then, in your `C#` assembly:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            flagTest.test T = new flagTest.test();
            T.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                String command = Console.ReadLine();

                if (command.ToLowerInvariant() == "stop")
                {
                    T.Stop();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This being said, this approach has nothing to do with multithreading. If you want to work with multithreading, you have to consider three important things:

1. how to save your workers progress when the threads are killed
2. how to implement a cancellation signal property
3. how to have control over the cancellation signal

This is just an example but it must be improved:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

for (Int32 i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    flagTest.test T = new flagTest.test();
    token.Register(() => T.Stop());

    Thread thread = new Thread(() => T.Start());
    thread.IsBackground = true;

    threads.Add(thread);

    thread.Start();
}
```

Then, when the user asks for a cancellation, just call:

```
cts.Cancel();
cts.Dispose();
```

Comment: Tommaso, Thank you very much for your help! However, I cannot figure out how to compile this class to a .NET dll since it seems we can only compile stand alone functions using the matlab deploytool. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747411/how-to-compile-matlab-class-into-c-lib), and still not 100% understand how that would work since the example in that link does not generate a `GlobalData` class in C++ code directly thus we cannot use the class and call another method in the class.

Comment: I was thinking about an alternative: bring all your loops outside Matlab and put them in the .NET assembly. Then, write your Matlab function so that it can process data with definite offsets, like DoWork(from,to) if possible. As this point you will be able to have full control over your threada since they will be one-sided.

Comment: Yes. That'll be another option that I have thought of and requires a lot of re-write of Matlab code to c#, which my teammates has decided not to go with......I was able to wrap a matlab function around a matlab class and compile that function as dll and call it from c#. However, the problem I face is that I don't know how to convert the matlab class to a MWArray object so I can change the the flag property inside the class. I think that will have to be another question I ask here. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Although I'm sure there is a way to do it with object instances, this answer provides another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841146/how-can-i-use-matlab-objects-in-compiled-net-assemblies